# Throttling navigation to prevent the browser from hanging in React App

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-router, react-hooks

I am working on Login/Register from in React and I am using firebase auth for authentication. When the user logged in I want to redirect the user on the root path or on App component. But I got into an infinite loop which gives me  this error (Throttling navigation to prevent the browser from hanging.)

```
    import React, { useEffect } from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";
    import App from "./App";
    import firebase from "firebase";
    import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, withRouter } from "react- 
router-dom";
    import Login from "./components/Login";
    import Register from "./components/Register";

    const Root = props => {
      useEffect(() => {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
          if (user) {
            props.history.push("/");
          }
        });
      });
      return (
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
        </Switch>
      );
    };

    const RootWithAuth = withRouter(Root);

    ReactDOM.render(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <RootWithAuth />{" "}
      </BrowserRouter>,
      document.getElementById("root")
    );
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is in useEfect, from [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html):

> If you’re familiar with React class lifecycle methods, you can think
>   of useEffect Hook as componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate, and
>   componentWillUnmount combined.

your infinite loop is because you are using useEfect currently also as componentDidUpdate, just add [ ] at the end of useEfect which will cause useEfect to act as componentDidMount.

```
useEffect(() => {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
          if (user) {
            props.history.push("/");
          }
        });
      }, []);
```

Comment: I forgot to put it there but finally, it works for me. Thank you so much